# ImportError: cannot import name get_uid 2

Tags: python, keras

I am using Python 2.7, with keras 1.2.2

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files   
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from glob import glob

# define function to load train, test, and validation datasets
def load_dataset(path):
    data = load_files(path)
    dog_files = np.array(data['filenames'])
    dog_targets = np_utils.to_categorical(np.array(data['target']), 133)
    return dog_files, dog_targets

# load train, test, and validation datasets
train_files, train_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/train')
valid_files, valid_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/valid')
test_files, test_targets = load_dataset('dogImages/test')

# load list of dog names
dog_names = [item[20:-1] for item in sorted(glob("dogImages/train/*/"))]

# print statistics about the dataset
print('There are %d total dog categories.' % len(dog_names))
print('There are %d total dog images.\n' % len(np.hstack([train_files, valid_files, test_files])))
print('There are %d training dog images.' % len(train_files))
print('There are %d validation dog images.' % len(valid_files))
print('There are %d test dog images.'% len(test_files))
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c760281b33b0> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.datasets import load_files
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from keras.utils import np_utils
      4 from glob import glob
      5 

C:\Users\ElPanda\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from . import backend
      3 from . import datasets
      4 from . import engine
      5 from . import layers

C:\Users\ElPanda\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 from .common import set_epsilon
      9 from .common import set_floatx
---> 10 from .common import get_uid
     11 from .common import cast_to_floatx
     12 from .common import image_dim_ordering

ImportError: cannot import name get_uid
```

I don't see any similar questions like with the appropriate answer. Any help would be great, will play the Harmonica at your wedding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten similar errors. It might have to do with the tensorflow version at the backend if you use tensorflow. The following versions worked for me.

Python ver 2.7

Keras ver 1.2.2

Tensorflow ver 1.3.0

Tensorflow ver 1.4.0 does not work in my case.